# How to sort a list on a column value

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to *sort* a `List<T>` in **LINQ** on two conditions,

1. If the list has the `MasterBenefitCode` property value as `"QLBEN"`. It should be sorted to the *top*.
2. Followed by all the benefits on benefit `Name`.

I'm trying with the following code,

```
employerBenefits
  .OrderBy(x => x.MasterBenefitCode == "QLBEN")
  .ThenBy(x => x.Name)
  .ToList();
```

Please let me know what am I missing here. Is it not possible to add a *comparison operator* in `OrderBy()`.

Comment: Since `false < true` we should put it as `.OrderByDescending(x => x.MasterBenefitCode == "QLBEN").`

Comment: Thank you for replying Dmitry. Worked as expected

Comment: @AryanM you should accept Dmitry's answer if his answer fits your needs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When comparing `Boolean` we have `false < true` (which is quite natural: `0 < 1`). So we have to sort in *descending* order (for `true` be on the top):

```
var result = employerBenefits
  .OrderByDescending(x => x.MasterBenefitCode == "QLBEN")
  .ThenBy(x => x.Name)
  .ToList();
```

**Edit:** The same with `ThenBy` which should be turned into `.ThenByDescending` (see comments below):

```
 var result = employerBenefits
   .OrderByDescending(x => x.MasterBenefitCode == "QLBEN") 
   .ThenByDescending(x => x.MasterBenefitCode == "QLBEF")
   .ThenBy(x => x.Name) 
   .ToList();
```

Comment: Request you to share your input on one more query. If I need to do sort the first two times on two values and then by Name. How do I do that.

employerBenefits
  .OrderByDescending(x => x.MasterBenefitCode == "QLBEN")
  .OrderByDescending(x => x.MasterBenefitCode == "QLBEF")
  .ThenBy(x => x.Name)
  .ToList();

Comment: @Aryan M: turn `ThenBy` into `ThenByDescending` as well (please, see my edit)

Comment: Cheers. Thanks mate

Answer (score 0):

Another Option to the same (including your comment of secondary MasterBenefitCode),

```
 var result = employerBenefits
                        .OrderByDescending(x => x.MasterBenefitCode == "QLBEN" ? 3:x.MasterBenefitCode == "QLBEF"?2:1)
                        .ThenBy(x => x.Name)
                        .ToList();
```